# why will strcpy only copy a limited number of elements:

Tags: c++, codeblocks, strcpy, strncpy

C++ newbie here. Writing a simple program. Everything works,except when I attempt to extract firstname and surname and print these individually, the number of letters printed in surname will always be the same size as the number in firstname. So if the name is will jackson, the program will print firstname as: will and second name as: jack. How do I solve this?

here is the code

```
for( i = 0; i < 19; i++)
  if(cAddress[i] == ' ' || cAddress[i] == '_' || cAddress[i] == '-' || cAddress[i] == '.')
    break;

strncpy(cFirst, cAddress, i);

cFirst[i] = '\0';
cout << endl << "\n";
cout << "Your first name is " << cFirst << endl;

strcpy(cSur,cAddress + i + 1);
cSur[i] = '\0';
cout << endl;
cout << "Your surname is " << cSur << endl;
```

Comment: What are the types of `cAddress`, `cFirst`, and `cSur`?  `char[]`?  `char*`?  `string`?

Comment: On a side note, if you're working in C++, there's usually very little reason to use the old C-style functions like `strcpy`.  You should investigate `std::string` instead, as it's much cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You are adding a `\0` character at the (i+1)th position - this marks the end of string, so that's all it prints. Before that line, cSur probably contains the entire surname.

Comment: cAddress, cFirst, and cSur are char arrays

Comment: Exactly, and when you add a `\0` character anywhere in the char array, that signifies "end of string." So remove that line and you should be fine :)

Comment: thank you. I tried removing the line and putting this in place  strcpy(cSur,cAddress + i + 1);
    if(cAddress[i] == '@')
    cSur[i] = '\0';  so that when the asterics is read the program realizes that this is the end of your surname. however this still doesn't work. so for an address like john.smith@hotmail.com, how could I extract smith?

Comment: @LegItJoe: If you want to find the @ in the name, you'll have to write a line to _find_ that first, similar to what you did with finding first/lastname seperators.

Answer (score 2):

Most of your code looks a lot like C -- and doesn't even take full advantage of the C standard library. In C++, I'd write something more like:

```
int pos = Address.find_first_of(" _-.");

std::string FirstName(Address, 0, pos);
std::string SurName(Address, pos);
```

If, for whatever reason, you insist on using C style strings, you might consider starting with [`strpbrk`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strpbrk) to find the separator.

Answer (score 0):

```
cSur[i] = '\0';
```

is incorrect.  i is the length of the first name.  cSur is already zero terminated by strcpy.

Having explained that, Jerry Coffin's answer is what I would recommend as good c++ code.